# PHP soap request with certifcate

Tags: php, soap

```
   $method ='MerchantFinancialOperationWS';


    $configs = array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' => false,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
        'local_cert' => $cert_file,
        'passphrase' => $cert_password
    );
    if($debug) $configs['trace'] = true;

    if(substr($url, -5) != '?WSDL') $url.= '?WSDL';
    $webService = new SoapClient($url, $configs);

$data = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fin="http://financial.services.merchant.channelmanagermsp.sibs/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Action>http://financial.services.merchant.channelmanagermsp.sibs/MerchantFinancialOperationWS/requestFinancialOperationRequest</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>https://enderecodeteste.pt</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <fin:requestFinancialOperation>
            <arg0>
                <messageType>N0003</messageType>
                <aditionalData>TESTE</aditionalData>
                <alias>
                    <aliasName>351#994999999</aliasName>
                    <aliasTypeCde>001</aliasTypeCde>
                </alias>
                <financialOperation>
                    <amount>400</amount>
                    <currencyCode>9782</currencyCode>
                    <operationTypeCode>022</operationTypeCode>
                    <merchantOprId>11111</merchantOprId>
                </financialOperation>
                <merchant>
                    <iPAddress>255.255.255.255</iPAddress>
                    <posId>880924 </posId>
                </merchant>
                <messageProperties>
                    <channel>01</channel>
                    <apiVersion>1</apiVersion>
                    <channelTypeCode>VPOS</channelTypeCode>
                    <networkCode>MULTIB</networkCode>
                    <serviceType>01</serviceType>
                    <timestamp>2014-10-31T13:58:49.2934+01:00</timestamp>
                </messageProperties>
            </arg0>
        </fin:requestFinancialOperation>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
  $result = $webService->requestFinancialOperation($data);
```

I've been trying to implement a soap request with a pem certificate and i'm just getting out of ideas. I know my code should be all wrong but i have no idea what the right direction is. I've been researching but found little no none documentation on this and the team behind the webservice i have to use also wasn't able to help.

I can already communicate with the service using SoapUI so i know the webservice works

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is you're sending XML when you may not need to.  PHP's built-in SOAP client will handle the XML for you, so you can focus on the objects (the O in SOAP!).  You need to construct a data structure (object or array) and pass that to the operation you want to run.  First look for the signature of the operation you want using:

```
$webService = new SoapClient($url, $configs);
var_dump($webService->__getFunctions());
```

This gives you the API - note that it indicates the data structures it expects in both the input parameters and the output.  To see what those data structures look like:

```
var_dump($webService->__getTypes());
```

Now you can construct a PHP object with the same fields and structure and pass it in.  Your code will look something along these lines:

```
$webService = new SoapClient($url, $configs);
$parameter = new stdClass();
$parameter->someField = 'N0003';
$parameter->anotherField = 'TESTE';
$result = $webService->requestFinancialOperation($parameter);
```